# What is faster: to call a user-declareed function within a query or to set the value by trigger?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

There is a declared MySQL function `GETUSERID()` returning an integer value. How to make a record insert faster: setting the value from inside a query like

```
INSERT INTO ttable 
(idtoset, some_other_field...) 
VALUES (GETUSERID(), value1...);
```

or call

```
INSERT INTO ttable 
(some_other_field...) 
VALUES (value1...);
```

and fill `idtoset` by a trigger that fires before insert?

What if the query is performing multiple row insert like

```
INSERT INTO ttable 
(idtoset, some_other_field...) 
VALUES (GETUSERID(), value1...), 
(GETUSERID(), value2...),
... 
(GETUSERID(), valueN...);
```

?

**Edit**

I have just investigated the answer of @Rahul. 
I created a ttest table with two triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tgbi` BEFORE INSERT ON `ttest` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.testint=1;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER `tgbi` BEFORE UPDATE ON `ttest` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.testint=2;
END;
```

If I am not mistaken, should the before insert trigger call `UPDATE SET` the second trigger is expected to fire as well and the created testint value might be =2, but it is =1 in every inserted row. Could that mean that the engine optimises INSERT procedure and sets the value simultaneously with that set manually by query?

**Appended** on request of @Rick-James. The question is not about the definite function. It is actually about any function. Any function will be called same number of times if the record is inserted from  trigger or from INSERT query. That is why I am wondering what is better from the point of MySQL engine - to call it manually setting the value in inserted records or filling it by means of triggers?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`***`@`***` FUNCTION `GETUSERID`() RETURNS int(10)
BEGIN
DECLARE id_no INT DEFAULT -1;
SELECT `id` INTO id_no FROM `tstuff` 
WHERE `tstuff`.`user_name`=
(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1)) LIMIT 1;
RETURN id_no;
END
```

Comment: Why not just use an `auto_increment` id?  Or `uuid()`?

Comment: @Gordon-Linof. This is a sample. Take any other user-defined function on your choice that returns an integer value selected or calculated from another table.

Comment: I don't think your `INSERT ... SET (...)` syntax is correct.

Comment: `TRIGGERs` have a lot of extra baggage.  A `STORED FUNCTION`, such as GETUSERID could have a lot of baggage; what is in it?

Comment: Sorry, @Rick-James, for mistyping. Corrected. The real code, certainly, works.

Comment: Dear @RickJames, I have appended the post. Thank you for your attention. The question is actually not about the exact function. I am wondering what is better for the engine - to call any function from INSERT statement or by trigger mechanism.

Comment: A _builtin_ function will be faster.  A `Stored Function` or a `UDF` -- it depends on what is in it.  If the Function and the Trigger have the same code, then it is harder to say.

Comment: This would be a little more efficient:  `WHERE tstuff.user_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1)`

Comment: Thank you, @RickJames for your advice. It seems, that a point from which the same function is called (from trigger or from query) does not matter, at least signifficantly.

Answer (score 2):

*What is faster?* No idea since I haven't done a bench marking on that but doing an direct `INSERT` operation would better to my knowledge instead of inserting and then perform an `UPDATE` through trigger.

Does what you are doing currently not working?  you can as well make it a `INSERT .. SELECT` operation like

```
INSERT INTO ttable (idtoset, some_other_field...) 
SELECT GETUSERID(), value1..., valuen FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thank you, the functions are working properly. I am just wondering what is faster. The idea that trigger calls an `UPDATE SET` is very interesting.

Comment: @asd-tm, as already mentioned; I have no idea what is faster but the sole point is : why having a trigger and perform insert+update when you can perform the job in a single insert.

Answer (score 1):

In past versions of MySQL, using a before insert trigger to populate a not nullable column didn't work as MySQL was evaluating the provided columns before the trigger. That's why whenever I have such a situation, I usually tend to go with functions instead of triggers.

From a performance point of view, since the before insert trigger is evaluated before actually writing data so the time needed to perform this is almost the same as immediately getting the value with the function and without trigger. But if all you are doing in the trigger is set the user ID, then I really see no reason to use a trigger.

Comment: Thank you, @benohead That is what I am supposing in the edit to my post. This is just a sample. I am trying to find if there is a real foundamental reason to prefer one method to another. An advantage to use a trigger in a more complex sample is to make the application code easier to read as the logics of other functions supported by MySQL server will be performed  on its side and such triggers will transparently work as default fields.